# finding a percentile value in mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, percentile

**NB! This question is related to Mysql 5.x and answers requiring v8.x does not help me here :-)**

I've found a way to calculate percentiles in php from an array of data (around 150.000 record), but it takes up alot of memory which makes php time out sometimes. I would like this calculation to happen through mysql 5.7 instead.

my table has a bunch of records with a date and a score (1000 records a day), and I would like to be able to find the top 10% value based on the scores from ie. one month.

My php calculation looks like this:

```
private function getPercentile($percentile, $array, $key) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            return null;
        }
        $array = $array[$key];
        sort($array);
        $index = ($percentile/100) * count($array);
        if (floor($index) == $index) {
            $result = ($array[$index-1] + $array[$index])/2;

        }
        else {
            $result = $array[floor($index)];
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Where I just take my mysql result array and put into the function after execution.

Table example:

| requestTime<timestamp> | score <double> |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-10 07:44:58 | 0.96 |
| 2021-08-11 07:44:52 | 0.73 |
| 2021-08-12 07:44:51 | 0.78 |

can anyone transition this into a mysql query, then I would be truly thankful!

Comment: So basically you want to find the score that is at 10%?

Comment: correct :) for a dataset of 150.000 records I want to know how good the score must be, to be in top 10% :-)

Comment: The accepted answer on the linked duplicate uses `@` variables. Ugh. That won't work in MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @SalmanA to the contrary, that solution works in v5.7, but will not work in v8.0.

Comment: @shadow it uses order by in a sub query which is not guaranteed to work as expected. The other answer is good though.